# Laravel 3, render only one section (for ajax)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'd like to reuse my templates and would like to return only one rendered section as an ajax response (html table) which belongs to the "content" section (index.blade.php).

```
@section('content')
html...
@endsection
```

I've created another layout called ajax (ajax.blade.php) which contains only:

```
@yield('content')
```

My controller:

```
class Some_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;
    public $layout = 'layouts.main';

public function get_index (){
if ( Request::ajax() )
 $this->layout = 'layouts.ajax';

$view = View::make('some.index')->with('data', 'shtg');

$this->layout->content = $view;
}
}
```

It works when I request the route via normal GET request... but when I request it via ajax I get an error:

```
Attempt to assign property of non-object
```

on the line containing

```
$this->layout->content = $view;
```

I've also tried

```
return Section::yield('content');
```

Which returns empty document.

Is there a way to return rendered section? I've searched over the forums and couldn't find anything apart from:

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2942

Which uses the same principle and doesn't work for me (I've tried all the variations mentioned on the link above).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing [blade templates](http://laravel.com/docs/views/templating#blade-layouts) with [controller templates](http://laravel.com/docs/views/templating#the-basics).  If you wish to use controller layouts (my preference) then remove the `@section('content')` and `@endsection`, and replace `@yield('content')` with `$content`.

However, that is not your entire problem.  The following line is picked up by the [layout method](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/routing/controller.php#L390-L398) and converted into a real view...

```php
public $layout = 'layouts.main';
```

You could easily extend the layout function in your controller, adding a layout_ajax attribute like this...

```php
/**
 * The layout used by the controller for AJAX requests.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $layout_ajax = 'layouts.ajax';

/**
 * Create the layout that is assigned to the controller.
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function layout()
{
    if ( ! empty($this->layout_ajax) and Request::ajax() )
    {
        $this->layout = $this->layout_ajax;
    }
    return parent::layout();
}
```